# Create vector satisfying two factor conditions in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R and having a heck of a time grappling with the syntax. Let's say I've got the following data frame data:

```
value   label    second
1       a        q
2       a        q
3       a        ASDF
4       b        q
6       b        QWERTY
6       b        QWERTY
7       c        q
8       c        q
9       c        q
10      d        q
```

Now, I want to get a vector of `df$second` which correspond to the maxima of `df$value` for a given value of `df$label`. So for instance, given `df$label = 'a'`, I want to return `'ASDF'`. For `df$label = 'b'`, I want to return `'QWERTY', 'QWERTY'`.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
max_value <- max(data$value[data$label == 'a'])
    result <- c()
    for (x in data$value){
        if (x == max_value){
            result <- c(result, data$second)
        }
    }
```

Now this does not generate the proper results vector. I'd like to figure out a way to do this with sapply, tapply, mapply etc. I'm just having trouble getting my head around these functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lapply( split(dat, dat$label),
       function(df) df[df$value == max(df$value), "second"] )
$a
[1] ASDF
Levels: ASDF q QWERTY

$b
[1] QWERTY QWERTY
Levels: ASDF q QWERTY

$c
[1] q
Levels: ASDF q QWERTY

$d
[1] q
Levels: ASDF q QWERTY
```

If you wanted to get rid of the factor baggage:

```
 lapply( split(dat, dat$label), 
    function(df) as.character(df[df$value == max(df$value), "second"]) )
$a
[1] "ASDF"

$b
[1] "QWERTY" "QWERTY"

$c
[1] "q"

$d
[1] "q"
```

To extract a particular leaf, set that result to a value and extract with "[[":

```
val <- lapply( split(dat, dat$label), 
    function(df) as.character(df[df$value == max(df$value), "second"]) )
val[["a"]]
#[1] "ASDF"
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Now how can I extract, say, the vector of maxima for factor 'b'? Is it as simple as

    x <- lapply(...)
    x[2]
?

Answer (score 3):

Straight forward in data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key="label")
DT[.(lab)][value==max(value), second]

# where `lab` is whatever label value you are trying to find
```

Note that if you want to do this for **all** values of `label`, just use the `by` argument:

```
DT[, c(.SD, mx=max(value)), by=label][value==mx, second, by=label]

   label second
1:     a   ASDF
2:     b QWERTY
3:     b QWERTY
4:     c      q
5:     d      q
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `base` R function:

```
df2 <- by(data = df, df$label, function(x) x[x$value == max(x$value), ])

# result as a list
df2
# df$label: a
# value label second
# 3     3     a   ASDF
# -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   df$label: b
# value label second
# 5     6     b QWERTY
# 6     6     b QWERTY
# -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   df$label: c
# value label second
# 9     9     c      q
# -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   df$label: d
# value label second
# 10    10     d      q

# ...or as a data frame
do.call(rbind, df2)
#     value label second
# a       3     a   ASDF
# b.5     6     b QWERTY
# b.6     6     b QWERTY
# c       9     c      q
# d      10     d      q
```